# Jquery iterating independently inside $each

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://codepen.io/rurounisena/pen/NeGjyq?editors=1111

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  addTargetClasses();
 checkReceived();
 });
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      var orgDates = $('table tr td span');
      
      var message = '';
      
      
      ///////////
      orgDates.each(function(i, elem) {
        
       
         parts = $(this).text().split('/');
        
         dt = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1,parts[1]).getTime();
          diffdate = Math.floor((dt - new Date().getTime()) / (86400 * 1000));
        
        if (diffdate === 0 || diffdate === -1) {
          return;
        }
        if (diffdate > 0 ||       $(this).parents('tr.targetRow').find('lastCell').hasClass('crossout')) {          
            return;          
        }

        if ((diffdate + 2) < 1) {
          
          if ((diffdate + 2) == 0) {
            diffdate = (diffdate + 1) + ' day ago';
          }
          else {
            diffdate = (diffdate + 1) + ' days ago';
          }
        }
  
        diffdate = diffdate.toString().slice(1);
        
        
        state = $(elem).parents('.targetTable tr.targetRow').find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
       mailType = $(elem).parents('.targetTable tr.targetRow').find(" td:nth-child(2)").text();
  
        message += state + ' ' + mailType + ' was due ' + diffdate + '<br/>';
  });

      $.alert({
        theme: "my-theme",
      
        title: "<span style='font-size:25px;'>"  + "</span>",
      content: "The following bulk is past the expected received date:"+ "<br/>" + "<br/>" + message,
        draggable: true,
        animationBounce: 1.5,
        buttons: {
          Dismiss: function() {
          }
        }
      });
      
      $('span[title*="Bulk Tracking"]').after("<button id='alert_btn' type='button'>See Alerts</button>");
      $('#alert_btn').after('<div id="emmacontainer" class="emmacontainer"><div class="container__inner"><div class="subDiv"></div> </div></div>');

      $('.subDiv').append(message);

      $('#emmacontainer').hide();
      $('#alert_btn').click(function(){
        $('#emmacontainer').slideToggle(400);
      });


    })
  })
  (jQuery);

  function addTargetClasses() {
      $("table[summary*='Bulk'] ").addClass("targetTable");
      $(".targetTable tr").addClass("targetRow");
  }

  function checkReceived() {
    $('.targetTable td.lastCell:contains("Received")').addClass('crossout');
      };
```

```css
    .crossout {
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    /* popup */
    .jconfirm.jconfirm-my-theme .jconfirm-box {
      background-color: #fdfdfd;
      border: 5px solid #003d5d;
      font-family: 'Hind Madurai', sans-serif;
      width: 40%;
    }
    .jconfirm.jconfirm-my-theme .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-content{
      width: 40%;
      border: 2px solid #00b4a9;
      padding: 5px;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .jconfirm.jconfirm-my-theme .jconfirm-box .jconfirm-buttons button{
      background-color: #96989a;
      color: #003d5d;
    }
    /* on click hidden div*/
    .emmacontainer {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .container__inner{
      background: #00b4a9;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      border: 10px solid #003d5d;
      box-sizing: border-box;

    }
    .subDiv {
      background-color: white;
      max-height: 80%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .emmacontainer div {
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: .5em;
      flex: 0 1 auto;

    }
    #alert_btn {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
      background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #599bb3), color-stop(1, #408c99));
      background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
      background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
      background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
      background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
      background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#599bb3', endColorstr='#408c99',GradientType=0);
      background-color:#00aba9;
      -moz-border-radius:8px;
      -webkit-border-radius:8px;
      border-radius:8px;
      display:inline-block;
      cursor:pointer;
      color:#ffffff;
      font-family:Arial;
      font-size:10px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding:8px 27px;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #alert_btn:hover {
      background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #408c99), color-stop(1, #599bb3));
      background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
      background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
      background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
      background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
      background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#408c99', endColorstr='#599bb3',GradientType=0);
      background-color:#408c99;
    }
    #alert_btn:active {
      position:relative;
      top:1px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='myDiv'>
    <table summary='Bulk Tracking'>
      <span title='Bulk Tracking'>Bulk Tracking</span>
      
      <tr>
        <td>IL</td>
        <td>NR</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/1/2018</span></td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Waiting For</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TX</td>
        <td>FT</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/9/2018</span></td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Waiting For</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>WY</td>
        <td>ND</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/25/2018</span></td>
        <td>721</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Waiting For</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MT</td>
        <td>NR</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/7/2018</span></td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Waiting For</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>AK</td>
        <td>LR</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/7/2018</span></td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Waiting For</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>VA</td>
        <td>ARR</td>
        <td><span class='ms-nowrap'>12/8/2018</span></td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td class='lastCell'>Received</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code works as intended. I loops through the dates in the table, checks whether or not they are past due, and outputs a string with the correlating data.
The problem is when there are a lots of items overdue the text inside the alert and button div become way too long. So I was hoping to group dates that are the same together to save some space. For example, instead of this:

- IL NR was due 13 days ago
- TX FT was due 5 days ago
- MT NR was due 7 days ago
- AK LR was due 7 days ago
- VA ARR was due 6 days ago

I would like it to read like this:

- IL NR was due 13 days ago
- TX FT was due 5 days ago
- MT NR, AK LR were due 7 days ago
- VA ARR was due 6 days ago

I have tried to iterate over the diffdate var and the $elem from the each loop but I never get what I expected as the output. I am relatively new to js and jquery so any help or advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: As with all such grouping type operations use an object (or Map) with days as keys and arrays as values. Then iterate the object to create the generated output

Comment: How can I do that without messing up the logic that checks that date difference? I was able get a result similar to the one I want but the logic was wrong.

Comment: You do all your date validations and instead of building one big string `message += state +...` you have a starting object to store the data in while looping. Then when loop is complete you compile the `message` from that object

Comment: So I would work with orgDates and not use the logic below it as it's laid out?

Comment: Something like `var messages ={}; orgDates.each... messages[datediff] = messages[datediff] ||[]; messages[datediff].push(text)` ... then when loop is completed iterate `messages` object

Comment: I wrote and ran your suggestion along with the iteration but keep getting diffDate is not defined. It is still in the same function so I didn't think scope would be an issue.

Comment: Ah nvm I got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediary step, where instead of adding the string

"IL NR was due 13 days ago"

to your results, instead add something more useful

["IL NR", -13]

create a function to take these results and convert them into the final strings you want to output (i.e. to take the input ["IL NR", -13] and output "IL NR was due 13 days ago") , but only after you merge your results based on the second (days past due) value of each element

Comment: that array has nothing to do with JSON which is a string data transfer format

Comment: @charlietfl Well he posted the code where he's calculating the diff dates. So I'm just suggesting that rather than creating strings there, that he create arrays or objects and by doing so make it easier to match up the diff dates

Comment: Fine but neither of those is JSON and calling it that helps propagate the misunderstanding of what JSON actually is

Comment: @charlietfl You are correct. I didn't understand your first comment, but I get it now and have corrected my answer